# In-line CTE in SQL

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Until today I thought that the CTE had to go before the main `SELECT` clause, but it appears that a `CTE` can be dropped into any subselect. As an example:

```
-- tested on BigQuery, Redshift, MySQL, Postgres
SELECT CONCAT(Odd.num, Even.num) FROM
  (WITH Numbers AS (SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 5) SELECT * FROM Numbers) Odd,
  (WITH Numbers AS (SELECT 2 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 6) SELECT * FROM Numbers) Even
```

Outside of just playing around with things though, is there ever a case for this sort of "embedded" CTE, or is there no reason to ever have it outside of the top, as if it's a variable declaration?

Comment: I didn't even know this syntax were possible, before reading your question.  AFAIK, this syntax would never be necessary while running on the database itself.  But maybe you would need it when going through e.g. a JDBC driver.

Comment: WITH is common query clause equal in rights to any other clause. Do not consider it like something special and exclusive. The query with CTEs can be used in any place (subquery or CTE) where the query w/o CTE can be used. And the only restriction is maximal nesting level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only that, you can have CTEs inside of CTEs.

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
  WITH CTE2 AS (
    …
  )
)
SELECT …
```

I had to work on someone’s query that did this 13 levels deep.  What a pain.  The main reason this isn’t good is that it makes a mess of readability.  I think what you are describing isn’t quite as bad as it keeps subsections of the query together.  Doing oddball things like this generally leads to confusion when others try to understand your query.

Comment: wow, why did someone keep nesting CTEs? Were they trying to do something they couldn't do otherwise?

Comment: Well that was a conversation we had (as you can imagine).  This was written by a software developer with limited SQL / data engineering experience.  Their explanation was that they could turn on the functionality from the inside out.  So basically they replaced nested sub-selects with nested CTEs.   This was years ago when Redshift interpreted CTEs as optimization walls so this made a completely unoptimizable query.

Comment: *why did someone keep nesting CTEs? Were they trying to do something they couldn't do otherwise?* In solid WITH clause the names of separate CTEs must be unique. Nested CTEs allows the names interference freely - each used name is accessible only in the query where it is defined and in its nested subquery/CTE, and it masks the same name from the upper nesting level (including source tables/views). In practice this can be useful when the query is built dynamically.

Comment: @Akina I see, thanks. Are you able to share any practical examples you can think of or links to some code that shows that?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 No, this is clear theory. In practice I have seen nested CTEs never.